# Why can't I update my Ember mug's firmware?

Tags: smart-home, hardware, kitchen-appliances

My Ember mug has a firmware update available, but when I try to update it the process fails at 50% during a reconnection step. How do I make sure the update is able to finish?

Comment: 80-180 minute battery life. How in the world can anyone possibly drink coffee so slowly that they need to keep their coffee warm this long?

Comment: I love coffee, but I get distracted very easily by my work as a software developer. I often work through an issue only to take a sip of coffee and be disgusted because it's lukewarm after an hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try filling your mug with boiling water before starting the update process. The mug detects when it's holding hot liquids and should properly reconnect during this step.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Still disconnected "unexpectedly".

Comment: There are a myriad of solutions online, this is the only one that ended up working for me. If you find a different solution that works for you can you post it as another answer here?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.  It is the interference from other devices. I kept getting to 50% for almost a week of trying.  Then, I took my phone and mug out on my back deck and it updated smoothly.   ...so take it outside, away from electrical interference.

Comment: I've also found this to be useful advice with pairing and communicating with other random Bluetooth IoT devices, such as a grill thermometer. Take just the device and the phone at least 20 meters away from any other Bluetooth, wifi, or other 2.4GHz transmitters and retry the operation.

Answer (score 2):

After the recommended reset, I tried it again not on the charger. That worked for me.